# Question about this proof that regular function on $P^n$ are constant

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand this proof from the following set of notes:
[https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~cb496/ag2007-final.pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ecb496/ag2007-final.pdf)

[image]

So my questions are: 1) why is it possible to pick a $x'$ in $V(G)$ that is not in $V(F)$?
2) Why is F and G constant enough to show that $\phi $ is in fact a constant? Because $F/G$ is just a local expression for $\phi$ , so can $phi$ take on different values away from the open set where it is expressed as $F/G$.

So I know these are probably too simple questions for most people here. I am just very new to algebraic geometry and I find many of these proofs confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Suppose by contradiction that $V(G)\subseteq V(F)$. Then by the homogeneous Nullstellensatz we obtain $\sqrt{(F)}\subseteq \sqrt{(G)}$. Denote by $\operatorname{rad(F)}$ resp. $\operatorname{rad(G)}$ the product of the distinct irreducible factors of $F$ resp. $G$, then $\sqrt{(F)}=(\operatorname{rad(F)})$ and $\sqrt{(G)}=(\operatorname{rad(G)})$, so $\operatorname{rad(G)}\mid\operatorname{rad(F)}$, condtradicting the fact that $F$ and $G$ are coprime.

(2) It is enough because $\mathbb{P}^n$ is irreducible, and hence any two open sets intersect. So the constant values on any two open sets must agree. In more topological language, what you showed is that $\phi$ is locally constant, and a locally constant function on a connected space is constant. As irreducible implies connected, $\phi$ must be constant.

And don't worry, it is confusing for everyone at first :)

Comment: That was very clear. Thank you! I was surprised that we needed the nullstellensatz. I thought the statement was suppose to be obvious or trivial, and while the application of the nullstellensatz was not hard, the nullstellensatz by itself takes a lot of algebraic machinery to prove.

Comment: hi, i would like to follow up and ask about the line "Since X is irreducible , FG'-F'G=0" so initially, I thougt the argument was just , we cross multiply and see that FG'=F'G on a non empty open subset and hence they must be equal on the closure which is P^n. thus FG'-F'G=0. But this cannot be correct since FG' does not even define a function on projective space. What should be the correct line of argument?

Comment: But I think I got it now: F/G-F'/G' is 0 on the open set. We can "clear denominators" and get FG'-F'G=0 on the open set and this is a homogeneous polynomial and zero sets are still well defined in  projective space. Since the zero set contains a nonempty open set, the zero set must be all of P^n so that should be it. So the only question I have left is, did we even had to choose F' and G' to be coprime? That seems unecessary. And again, I want to thank you for your very clear and helpful answers.

Comment: @Bill yes I think you don't need to take $F'$ and $G'$ to be coprime. But you can, and it doesn't hurt, and most of the time it is a good idea, as then $F'/G'$ is defined on a bigger set :)